# Como modificar un campo de un registro de una columna generada en SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-management

como mencione en la pregunta me gustaria poder editar o cambiar un campo de un registro de columnas que genere pero la verdad no eh visto algo como eso y no estoy seguro de si se puede por eso pido su ayuda para saber que puedo realizar para obtener el resultado que busco.
Primero que nada esta es mi consulta:

```
with 
Prueba as(
select A.IdEmpleado, 
       A.Posicion,
       A.supervisor ,
       A.name+' '+A.lastName as 'NombreEmpleado', 
       B.name+' '+B.lastName as 'Manager 1', 
       C.name+' '+C.lastName as 'Manager 2',
       D.name+' '+D.lastName as 'Manager 3'
from Empleados A 
left join Empleados B ON A.supervisor = B.IdEmpleado
left join Empleados C ON B.supervisor = C.IdEmpleado
left join Empleados D ON C.supervisor = D.IdEmpleado
)
select * from Prueba
```

Y bueno, lo que busco es que de los registros que trae mi consulta los campos con NULL yo poder cambiarlos por algun valor que yo le especifique, en este caso digamos que quiero cambiar los registros de 20 empleados de las 3 columnas que genere que son Manager 1,2 y 3...Como podria hacer esto?

Comment: Has probado con `ISNULL()` o `COALESCE()`?

Comment: No, la verdad no se como funcionan... ademas lo que quiero es editar los campos con null, no solo traer los registros con null. Perdon si con lo que me recomendaste se puede hacer lo que busco pero la verdad no se como funciona por eso pido ayuda para que me expliquen un poco y seguir yo con el problema, gracias!

Comment: Inténtalo. Hay documentación oficial, la revisaste?

Comment: Si, ya le estoy dando una revisado... pero si tienen algo un poco más facil de entender me lo podrian mostrar la verdad no entiendo como hacer lo que les mencione con eso, solo entiendo que con eso puedo traer valores nulos o no llamarlos y traer los demas

Comment: No entiendo como eso me puede ayudar hacer lo que mencione

Comment: Te ayuda a hacer justo lo que dijiste, en este caso querés devolver querés cambiar ciertos valores donde X campo sea nulo, ISNULL si leíste la documentación, valida si X campo es nulo si usas un CASE puedes especificar que si es nulo, coloque X registro. Esto solo es para consultas si quieres modificar los valores de la tabla necesitarías un update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IsNull()**.

La función cambia el valor del primer parámetro cuando este viene como Null, por el segundo parámetro.

```
Select ISNULL(Null, 'x') as col1;
```

[image: Res1]

Por tanto podemos aplicar la función a una columna y si la misma para una fila tiene Null (o ausencia de valor), entonces, la resolverá con el valor que le pongamos por defecto.

```
Create table ejemploNull (id int, col1 varchar(100));
Insert into ejemploNull (id, col1)
values
(1,Null),
(2,'a');
```

Y con las filas creadas.

```
Select id, ISNULL(col1, 'sustituto') as col1
From ejemploNull;
```

[image: Res2]

El valor que sustituye puede ser algo que venga de otra columna, o variable. O una expresión...

```
Select id, ISNULL(col1, cast(id as varchar))
From ejemploNull;
```

[image: Res3]

Observa que le he quitado el alias de columna y por tanto la salida, es la que resuelve la función, y no sabe como se llama esa columna.

**Coalesce()**

Es muy similar, pero esta retorna el primer valor que no sea Null, de entre las columnas que le pases como parámetro.

No está limitada a 1 parámetro.

```
Alter table ejemploNull
Add 
col2 varchar(10),
col3 varchar(10),
col4 varchar(10);
```

Ahora introducimos una filas.

```
Insert into ejemploNull (id, col1, col2, col3, col4)
Values
(3,'b','col2b',Null, Null),
(4,'c','col2c','col3c', Null),
(5,'d','col2d','col3c', 'col4d');
```

[image: Res4]

Usando la función coalesce, podemos hacer algo así.

```
SELECT id, 
COALESCE(col4,col3,col2,col1) as columna
FROM ejemploNull;
```

[image: Res]

Por tanto coalesce, devuelve el primer valor que no sea Null. Empezando por la izquierda, como la fila de `id=5` tiene en `col4` un `valor = col4d`, esta es su salida.

Como la fila `id=4` tiene en `col4` un `Null` pero en `col3` un `valor = col3c`, esta es su salida. Y así sucesivamente.

**Solución**

```
with 
Prueba as(
select A.IdEmpleado, 
       A.Posicion,
       A.supervisor ,
       Concat(A.name, A.lastName) as NombreEmpleado,
       Concat(B.name, B.lastName) as [Manager 1], 
       Concat(C.name, C.lastName) as [Manager 2],
       Concat(D.name, D.lastName) as [Manager 3]
from Empleados A 
left join Empleados B ON A.supervisor = B.IdEmpleado
left join Empleados C ON B.supervisor = C.IdEmpleado
left join Empleados D ON C.supervisor = D.IdEmpleado
)
select 
      IdEmpleado 
    , Posicion
    , supervisor 
    , NombreEmpleado
    , IsNull([Manager 1], 'alternativo1') As [Manager 1]
    , IsNull([Manager 2], 'alternativo2') As [Manager 2]
    , IsNull([Manager 3], 'alternativo3') As [Manager 3]
from Prueba;
```

Es la misma query, aplicando la función Isnull a la salida de la cte.

Te he aplicado un pequeño cambio, en vez del operador `+`, la función `concat`, ya que si para una fila `Name` o `LastName` tienen `Null` en una de las dos partes, con el operador `+` te retornaría `Null` y con la función `Concat`, te retornará sólo el name o solo el lastName según sea.

[IsNull ¿Cómo funciona?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/17/isnull-una-de-las-funciones-mas-usadas/)

[Coalesce. La competencia de IsNull](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/27/coalesce-o-la-competencia-de-isnull/)

[Concat. Concatenar cadenas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/02/sql-server-concatenar-cadenas/)

Comment: Ok, pero mi pregunta tambien seria teniendo como ejemplo la tabla ejemploNull que hiciste si puedo cambiar un campo en especifico, es decir si quiero cambiar solo el NULL del registro con id 3 de la columna 4

Comment: `Case when id = 3 then isNull(....blab...bla) else col end` y así aplicas solo ese isnull a una fila

Comment: Listo! tuve un problema pero ya lo pude arreglar, te agradezco mucho la ayuda :)